# Matlab: Using a Variable in Address of Loading

Tags: matlab

A text file could be loaded as below:

```
load sourceETA/Record1/result1.txt
```

How can I use a variable in address of loading? For example (n is a variable):

```
[load 'sourceETA/Record1/result',num2str(n),'.txt']
```

But the above code doesn't work! How do I do?

Comment: If you would have just typed `help load` into Matlab you'd have your answer.

Comment: That wasn't help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html, shows that you can supply a string to `load` by doing:

```
load(filename)
```

where filename is a string.  In your case, you can do:

```
load(['sourceETA/Record1/result',num2str(n),'.txt'])
```